# ODE satisfied by the error vector in differential geometry

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, curves, calculus-of-variations, perturbation-theory

Consider a control system of the form $\dot x(t) = f(x(t),u(t))$ where $x$ takes his values  in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$.
Here is what I read:

Let $x^*$ be a reference curve associated to the control $u^*$. Take a $L^1$-perturbation of $u^*$ defined by $u_\varepsilon(t) := v \in U$ on $[s,s+\varepsilon[$, where $s \in [0,T[$ is a Lebesgue time of the function $t \mapsto f(x^*(t),u^*(t))$, and $u_\varepsilon(t) := u^*(t) $ elsewhere. The corresponding variation vector satisfies the linear equation 
$$
\dot w(t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x^*(t),u^*(t)) \ w(t), \quad \forall a.e. t \in [s,T] , \qquad \qquad (1)
$$
and the initial condition 
$$w(s)=f(x^*(s),v)-f(x^*(s),u^*(s)).$$

---

how do they get the equation $(1)$ ?
If I understand $w=x_\varepsilon - x$, hence using a Taylor expansion for each $t$ at $(x^*,u^*)$, we have

$$
\dot w = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}^\intercal(x^*,u^*) \ w + \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}^\intercal(x^*,u^*)\ (u_\varepsilon-u^*)
$$
why they do not have the term in $u$ ?

Comment: Equation (1) holds for $t\in[s,T]$ where $u_\epsilon(t)=u^*(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $$w(t) = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}1/\varepsilon\ (x(t,u_\varepsilon) - x(t,u^*))= \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(v-u^*)+... \qquad (1)$$.
where $u_\varepsilon=u^* + \varepsilon (v-u^*)$
We have 
$$
x(t,u_\varepsilon) = x_0 + \int_0^t f(x(s,u_\varepsilon(s)),u_\varepsilon)ds
$$
and 
$$
f(x(s,u_\varepsilon(s)),u_\varepsilon) = f(x(s,u^*),u^*) + \varepsilon \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x(s,u^*),u^*)\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(v-u^*) + \varepsilon \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(x(s,u^*),u^*)(v-u^*) + o(\varepsilon^2)
$$
hence
$$
x(t,u_\varepsilon) = x(t,u^*) + \varepsilon\int_0^t  (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x^*,u^*)\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(v-u^*) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(x^*,u^*)(v-u^*))ds +...
$$

and finally, using (1),
$$
\dot w = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x^*,u^*)\ w + \varepsilon\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(x^*,u^*)(v-u^*).
$$

With the same spirit we can get (1) using the notion of Lebesgue time.